# Non trivial boundaries for laplacian equation on rectangle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, potential-theory

1) Can this Laplace equation, with its non trivial boundaries (on a
rectangular domain), be solved analytically?

$$\frac{d^2U}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2U}{dy^2}=0$$
$$U_x(0,y)=0\quad,\quad U_x(a,y)=f(y)$$
$$U_y(x,0)=0\quad,\quad U(x,b)=0$$

$f(y)$ is a function described as a vector (discrete values) which I cant describe as a continuous function.

2) If the answer to (1) is no, is there an easy procedure to solve
it numerically (I don't have much experience with numerics or time to
study it deeply)

The difficulty arises because $b>>>a$
$$b=0.1\quad,\quad a=1e-5$$

Thanks.

Comment: This problem can be solved by separation, i.e., you can assume that $U(x,y) = U_1(x) U_2(y)$.

Comment: [Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplacesEqn.aspx) you can find some information about how to obtain the solution.

Comment: I know the methods in general but because this is a mixed boundary condition problem I'm not quite sure how to solve the $"y"$ part.

$$U_2(y)=a\cos(\lambda y)+b\sin(\lambda y)$$
$$U_2'(y)=-a\lambda\sin(\lambda y)+b\lambda\cos(\lambda y)$$
$$U_2'(0)=0=b\lambda\Rightarrow\lambda=0\ or\ b=0$$
$$\lambda_0=0\Rightarrow U_{2,0}=a_0$$
$$U_{2,n}(b)=a_n\cos(\lambda_n y)\Rightarrow\lambda_n=\frac{\pi}{2}(1+2n)$$
$$U_{2,n}(y)=a_0+a_n\cos(\lambda_n y)$$
Is this correct?

so finally I'll get
$$U=a_0+\sum_n A_n\cosh(\lambda_nx)\cos(\lambda_ny)$$

Comment: And I saw in some places that I need to make sure that 

$$a_0=0\Rightarrow\int_{0}^{\infty}f(y)dy=0$$

Comment: If we can assume that $f(0)=0$, then let $w=U-\frac{1}{a(a-b)}x(x-b)f(y)$, and solve the problem for $w$ instead.